# How to create custom ToggleButton style in Android?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-togglebutton

I am wanting to create a custom `ToggleButton` style, mainly so I can change the minimum height and text size depending on the screen size.

I have already done this for `Button`:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/button_min_height</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text_size</item>
</style>
```

And I am now wanting to do a similar thing for `ToggleButton`. I have tried this...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/MyToggleButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToggleButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ToggleButton">
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/button_min_height</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text_size</item>
</style>
```

...but `Widget.AppCompat.ToggleButton` doesn't exist. So what changes do I need to make so I can control the minimum height and text size of my `ToggleButton`s like I already do for `Button`s?

I would prefer an approach similar to the above, not only for consistency but so I don't have to go through all my layout files and update the `ToggleButton`s' xml individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/MyToggleButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToggleButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Button.Toggle">
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/button_min_height</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text_size</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Using your code, my **ToggleButton**s looks very different to my other **Button**s on the UI, so I changed your `parent="android:Widget.Button.Toggle"` to `parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Toggle"` and now they look spot on. Thank you.

Comment: For MaterialTheme: android:Widget.Material.Button.Toggle